# get to all attribute value using xpath

Tags: xpath

this is my xml file:-

```
<results value="1">
    <result value="111">
        <Country_Code value="IN"/>
        <Country_Name value="India"/>
        <Region_Name value="Gujarat"/>
        <City  value="Rajkot"/> 
        <loction lat="13.060422" lng="80.24958300000003"/>
    </result>
    <result value="222">
        <Country_Code value="KE"/>
        <Country_Name value="Kenya"/>
        <Region_Name value="Vihiga"/>
        <City value="Kakamega"/> 
        <loction lat="0.1182473" lng="34.7334515999997"/>
    </result>
</results>
```

this is my code:-

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var xml;
        $.get(
        "sea.xml",
        null,
        function (data) {
            xml = data;
        },
        "xml"
    );

        function get_list(ls) {
            var elName = $('#select').val();
            var value = $('#value').val();
            if(elName == "" || value == "")
            {
            }
            else if (elName != "" || value != "")
            {
            var xPath = '//*[ @lat '+ ls +' "'+elName+'" and @lng '+ ls +' "'+value+'"]'+'/../City/@*';


            var iterator = xml.evaluate(xPath, xml.documentElement, null,
                XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
            var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
            var str = '';
            while (thisNode) {
                if (str) {
                    str += ', ';
                }
                str += thisNode.textContent;
                thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
            }

            $("#result").text(str);
        }
        else 
        {}
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="select">
    <input type="text" id="value">
    <input type="button" name="button" value="Search" onclick="get_list('=')">
    <div id="result">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

with this code xpath return attribute value `Rajkot` but i want to change in Xpath to get all the attribute

with help of xPath if value match on xml file return only city attribute value.
but i want to all attribute value like:- `IN,Inida,Gujarat,Rajkot,13.060422,80.24958300000003`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XPath:

```
//loction[@lat='13.060422' and @lng='80.24958300000003'][1]/preceding-sibling::City/@value
```

Outputs:

```
 value="Rajkot"
```

---

And the following XPath:

```
//loction[@lat='13.060422' and @lng='80.24958300000003'][1]/preceding-sibling::*/@*
```

Outputs:

```
 value="IN"
-----------------------
value="India"
-----------------------
value="Gujarat"
-----------------------
value="Rajkot"
```

Comment: no man you dont understand my requirement. if lat and lang value match than return there same level node attribute value here i am edit my question please check...

Comment: if we enter in textbox 13.060422 and 80.24958300000003 then return IN Gujarat Rajkot 13.060422 80.24958300000003 this type at right now return only one attribute Rajkot b'coz i set in end of xpath /../City/@*

Comment: yes great good job dear but any idea when xml file have no attribute than which type of xpath set xml like<results>
 `<result>
  <Country_Code>IN</Country_Code>
  <Country_Name>India</Country_Name>
  <Region_Name>Gujarat</Region_Name>
  <City>Rajkot</City> 
  <lat>13.060422</lat>
  <lng>80.24958300000003</lng>
 </result>
 <result>
  <Country_Code>KE</Country_Code>
  <Country_Name>Kenya</Country_Name>
  <Region_Name>Vihiga</Region_Name>
  <City>Kakamega</City> 
  <lat>0.1182473</lat>
  <lng>34.7334515999997</lng>
 </result>
</results>`

Comment: It could be something like: //result[lat='13.060422' and lng='80.24958300000003']/node()/text()