# What can I do to select an attribute value using XPATH query?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, jdom

I am pretty new in XPATH and I have the following problem:

I have this XML content:

```
<root><status>
  <id>0</id>
  <message>MY MESSAGE</message>
</status>
<drivers>
<drive id="my ID">
  <property1>0</property1>
  <property2>104857600</property2>
  <property3 />
</drive></drivers>
</root>
```

What have I to do to select the **attribute value** named **id** (I wanto select the **"my ID** value)

Can you help me?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543602/get-to-all-attribute-value-using-xpath

Comment: @vcsjones That's a syntax error.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Blarg - missed the slash, that should be `/root/drivers/drive/@id`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To get the attribute node, you can do:

```
/root/drivers/drive/@id
```

or

```
/root/drivers/drive/attribute::id
```

In most cases this will automatically be converted to a string ('atomized') for you, but in a case where you need to ensure that you are getting back a string value, you can also do:

```
/root/drivers/drive/@id/string()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
/root/drivers/drive[1]/@id/text()
```

equivalent to:

```
//drive[1]/@id/text()
```

See there for more XPATH syntax explanation: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_intro.asp